# What would cause a video encoded with HandBrake to become distorted (playing in slo-mo)?

Tags: windows-7, video, encoding, handbrake

I'm trying to encode a video using HandBrake, but every time I try it seems to make the video twice as long and half the speed.

I've tried default options for different H.264 formats with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What OS / Platform are you using? I had some issues with Handbraked video's when I had an old EyeTV Plugin installed to Quicktime's plugin folder...  This might also apply to old DIVX plugins as well, since EyeTV bundles a version of Divx.

Comment: I'm running Windows 7. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Do you have any older DIVX plugins loaded?  Chances are that it is an interaction between some old video codecs...